# How to stack imgs on top of img?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have six of my portfolio images (of kittens). How do I stack six of them on top of the lake wallpaper? I don't want there to be any white space, just the word "Portfolio" and six kittens on top of the lake, followed by the grey background section of the website.

***Portfolio - How do I make six kitten photos on top of the lake img?***

**About - Grey background with white font and profile pic (Already done)**

**Contact - Contact form (Already done)**

I've read about z-index, and tried background-size: cover and contain, but it doesn't seem to work... Can anyone explain all this to me?

**HTML**

```
<header id="portfolio" class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="font-italic">Portfolio</h1>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/300" alt="Porfolio1" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/300" alt="Porfolio2" class="img-thumbnail>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/300" alt="Porfolio3" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row portfolio-buffer">
            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/300" alt="Porfolio4" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4"> 
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/300" alt="Porfolio5" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/350/300" alt="Porfolio6" class="img-thumbnail">
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</header>
```

**CSS**

```
.portfolio-buffer {
   margin-top: 30px; 
}

section {
   padding: 85px 0;
}

footer {
   padding: 40px 0;
}

#portfolio > img {
   margin-left: -15px; /* Compensate for the container */
   width: calc(100% + 30px); /* Compensate for the container */
}
```

https://codepen.io/jenlky/pen/GMENBL/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **numerous** problems with your fiddle:

1. Your `.wallpaper` selector doesn't actually have a matching element; you have no element with a class of `wallpaper`.
2. You are using Boostrap's `container-fluid`, but not using a column-based layout. Your elements in this container that are **not** in Bootstrap rows (such as this background) need to have `margin-left` and `margin-right` of `-15px` to accommodate for Boostrap.
3. You have rows that have combined columns counts other than 12.
4. **Most** elements overflow their container.

As for the background not working with `background-size`, that is because `background-size` requires a **background** to operate, added via a CSS property like `background: url(background.jpg)`. You are simply using an `<img>` tag.

Having said that, all you need to do is make sure that your image has a `max-width` of `100%`, to ensure that it stays within the bounds. You'll probably also want to make it fixed to the page, which can be done with `position: fixed`.

I've created a new selector based on your current structure, and added the relevant properties:

```
#portfolio > img {
  margin-left: -15px; /* Compensate for the container */
  margin-right: -15px; /* Compensate for the container */
  max-width: 100%;
  position: fixed; /* Optional */
}
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/dVVpmY)**.

Note that you'll probably want to add `max-width: 100%;` and `max-height: 100%;` to **all** images, to ensure that they don't go outside of their container.

#### Update

In order to have the background only cover the portfolio section, you'll want to remove `position: fixed` (to give it the default position `relative`). You'll still want to keep the negative left margin, but you'll want to make it `100%` of the width of the container **plus** 30 pixels in order to compensate for the padding and offset. That can be done with a CSS calculation:

```
#portfolio > img {
  margin-left: -15px; /* Compensate for the container */
  width: calc(100% + 30px); /* Compensate for the container */
}
```

I've created a new pen showcasing this **[here](https://codepen.io/Obsidian-Age/pen/BwwQjx)**.

And again, note that you'll probably want to set a `max-width` of `100%` on **all** images, and you should set `margin-left` (and technically `margin-right`) on all elements that are directly under a Bootstrap column. For example, the cats can be fixed with:

```
.col-md-4 > img.img-absolute {
    margin-left: -15px;
    margin-right: -15px;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply! This is my first time making a website, pardon the messiness of the code. Edited: I wanted to make the wallpaper occupy the Portfolio section of the website, which is above the About section, not the whole page.

Comment: No problem, and that makes way more sense in terms of the background colours! I've updated my answer to cover that :)

Comment: I've made the changes u said. The wallpaper occupies the top section of the website nicely, but the portfolio photos still doesn't stack on top of and in the middle of the wallpaper.  Can u take a look at my codepen again?

Comment: The pen is certainly looking a lot better now, though I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the photos not stacking "*on top of and in the middle of the wallpaper*"? They appear to be on top of the white section. Do you want them on top of the image itself? Should the white section be shifted up as well? In order to have them on **top** of the background, you really should be using CSS's `background` property, rather than an imagine. You could use negative `margin-top`, but that would mess other things up.

Comment: I want to make the six photos be on top of the image itself, without the white section. U mean that I should be using CSS's background property rather than an image? Ok I'll try that out.

Answer (score 0):

Ok thanks to Obsidian Age for giving me the idea of using background-image instead of img src="...". So I removed img src and added this in:

```
header {
    background-image: url("https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/forest_lake_reflection_island_mist_97668_1920x1080.jpg");
    padding: 85px 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

That works and solved the problem I had. I've updated in my codepen (https://codepen.io/jenlky/pen/GMENBL/). Cheers!